# Show hide payment gateways based on checkout fields in Woocommerce

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

In Woocommerce checkout page, I am trying to hide some payment gateways, keeping only **"Cash on delivery"** payment method (COD) when **"Ship to a different address?"** is checked.

I have tried [Conditionally hiding et showing payment gateways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42513500/conditionally-hiding-et-showing-payment-gateways/42521529#42521529) with some changes, but I didn't worked. I have tried also different answer codes without succes.

How to keep only COD payment when **"Ship to a different address?"** is checked?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will hide all payment gateways except **"Cash on delivery"** (COD) when **"Ship to a different address?"** is checked *(and the shipping checkout fields are shown)*:

```
// The jQuery Ajax request
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'checkout_billing_area_script' );
function checkout_billing_area_script() {
    // Only checkout page
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ):

    // Remove "ship_different" custom WC session on load
    if( WC()->session->get('ship_different') ){
        WC()->session->__unset('ship_different');
    }
    // jQuery Ajax code below
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        if (typeof wc_checkout_params === 'undefined')
            return false;

        var a = '#ship-to-different-address-checkbox', b = '';

        // Ajax function
        function triggerSTDA( value ){
             $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action': 'ship_different_address',
                    'ship_different': value,
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
                    console.log(result); // For testing (to be removed)
                }
            });
        }

        $(a).on( 'change', function(){
            b = $(this).prop('checked') === true ? 'yes' : 'no';
            triggerSTDA( b );
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}

// The Wordpress Ajax PHP receiver
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ship_different_address', 'get_ajax_ship_different_address' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ship_different_address', 'get_ajax_ship_different_address' );
function get_ajax_ship_different_address() {
    if ( isset($_POST['ship_different']) ){
        WC()->session->set('ship_different', esc_attr($_POST['ship_different']));
        echo $_POST['ship_different'];
    }
    die();
}

// Show/hide payment gateways
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'conditionally_hide_payment_gateways', 100, 1 );
function conditionally_hide_payment_gateways( $available_gateways ) {
    if( WC()->session->get('ship_different') == 'yes' ) {
        foreach( $available_gateways as $gateways_id => $gateways ){
            if( $gateways_id !== 'cod' ) {
                unset($available_gateways[$gateways_id]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Comment: it breaks the menu system in wordpress

Comment: @JonnyKapula This is because your other customization or your theme customization or a plugin. This code works and doesn't break anything.

Comment: weird since I'm using a fresh install of WP with Woo without any plugins. by menu system I mean in wp admin, the menu is "greyed out".

Comment: @JonnyKapula I have tested that on a fresh install using WP 5.2 WC3.6.3 and Last storefront theme version and it works perfectly. So there is something else that is making trouble in your case. Also I kindly remember you, that when you are using any existing stackOverFlow answer, don't forget to upvote it, (a very small reward for the author that cost you a click so one second of your time).