# TillPayments Woocommerce plugin - how to show all payment gateways on Customer Payment Page

Tags: woocommerce, payment-gateway

I have a number of payment gateways (some custom) on my Woocommerce shop for different use scenarios. One of those is set to 'Pay Later', allowing clients to place the order, have an invoice sent to them so they can send the invoice to their accounts team for payment via EFT or a company CC. This has been working well for the last 8 years.

We are now integrating TillPayments as a payment solution to replace a number of others. When I installed the TillPayments plugin (https://github.com/tillpayments/woocommerce-plugin), the Customer Payment Page started only showing the payent gateway selected at checkout, that being 'Pay Later' for all customers who are visiting that page as those are the only orders that require payment. So when someone comes back to pay for their order after opting to 'Pay Later', 'Pay Later' is the only available option and they are stuck in a loop. For reference, I have tried this process with other payment gateways and whichever one selected at checkout is the one that is returned.

I assume the following section in till-payments-creditcard.php is the cause of this, but not being an expert I could be wrong:

```
public function hide_payment_gateways_on_pay_for_order_page($available_gateways)
    {
        if (is_checkout_pay_page()) {
            global $wp;
            $this->order = new WC_Order($wp->query_vars['order-pay']);
            foreach ($available_gateways as $gateways_id => $gateways) {
                if ($gateways_id !== $this->order->get_payment_method()) {
                    unset($available_gateways[$gateways_id]);
                }
            }
        }

        return $available_gateways;
    }
```

**Question: How do I display ALL the payment gatways available?**

I've tried removing that block, changing `if ($gateways_id !== $this->order->get_payment_method())` to `if ($gateways_id == $this->order->get_payment_method())` but that has either returned no gateways or generated an error.

Comment: Just comment the unset(…) line like `// unset($available_gateways[$gateways_id]);`, it should solve your issue. Then to hide your "Pay later" payment method in "Order pay" page, use something like [Conditionally hiding et showing payment gateways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42521529/3730754) making the necessary changes to the code to fulfill your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response @LoicTheAztec, I have tried that and it has made no difference. Maybe I am looking at the wrong part of the file. I will keep looking, if anyone has experience with Till Payments it would be great to hear about your experience.

Comment: Update: I found the files that needed to be changed and you were absolutely correct, it just needed to be edited in 3 separate files. Legendary work, thanks mate.